# Error in grub-efi-amd64-signed after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: apt, grub2, uefi, 20.04

Yesterday I've updated my Ubuntu and an error occurred while upgrading but I didn't attention to that.

Now when I try to execute apt commands like `sudo apt upgrade` It gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.139+2.04-1ubuntu24) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-efi-amd64-signed.postinst: 23: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've also checked similar problems but none of them worked for me. So how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're helping to test the development release (*focal fossa* isn't 20.04 until release time), then you can also use #ubuntu-quality via IRC or telegram, however general support should still go to #ubuntu+1 sites until *focal fossa* has been released and reached stable 20.04).   *You didn't specifically give a release, but you tagged focal fossa or ubuntu+1 / development release*  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I know you don't support beta testers, but if anyone has any information, I'd love to read it.  At this point I'm scared to restart.

Rob